# Efficient way to reverse a large iterator

Tags: python, iterator

This may sound a bit insane but I have an iterator with `N = 10**409` elements. Is there a way to get items from the end of this "list"? I.e. when I call `next(iterator)` it gives me what I want to be the last thing, but to get to what I want to be first thing I would need to call `next(iterator)` N times.
If I do something like `list(iterator).reverse()` it will of course crash due to lack of memory.

Edit: how the iterator is being used with a simplified example:

```
# prints all possible alphabetical character combinations that can fit in a tweet
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
cproduct = itertools.product(chars,repeat=250)
for subset in cproduct:
    print(''.join(subset))

# will start with `aaaaaaaa...aaa`
# but I want it to start with `zzz...zzz`
```

Comment: `reversed(iterator)` might work.

Comment: @Kraigolas won't that have the same problem as `list(iterator).reverse()`?

Comment: You can't reverse an iterator without first consuming the iterator entirely. What is the nature/origin of the iterator? Is this something you are able to change?

Comment: @MarkRansom Probably. If the iterator is custom, you can implement `__reversed__` so that it doesn't create the entire list, but in general you cannot reverse the iterator.

Comment: @IainShelvington the function of the iterator is to find the cartesian product, so I am using `itertools.product`. From what it sounds like I may need to create a custom version of `itertools.product` so that it has a `__reversed__`?

Comment: Just compute the element you want directly. Don't go through `itertools.product`.

Comment: @NullSalad can you add your usage of `itertools.product` to your question? Could you not just reverse the iterables before you pass them to `itertools.product` (might need to change the order too...)?

Comment: Save the iterator results to a harddisk. Although, in your case of `N = 10**409`, I think you might need more atoms than are in the universe. :)

Comment: Also, won't iterating through all those elements take several trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion trillion years?

Comment: haha all very true statements. I could possibly add relevant elements to the HDD and remove them as the iterator progresses. I added a "simplified" example of how I am using `itertools.product`

Comment: @NullSalad if you want the iterator reversed, wouldn't you start with "zzz....."?

Comment: `cproduct = itertools.product(reversed(chars), repeat=250)` would give you the products in reverse order?

Comment: apologies, I want it to start with "zzzz..." and not "aaaa...", typo on my end, updating the example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some problems, you can compute the elements in reverse. For the example you provide, one can simply reverse the items you are taking the product of.

In this example, we reverse the symbols before taking the product to get the "reverse iterator":

```
>>> symbols = "abc"

>>> perms = itertools.product(symbols, repeat=5)
>>> perms = ["".join(x) for x in perms]
>>> perms
['aaaaa', 'aaaab', 'aaaac', 'aaaba', 'aaabb',
 ...,
 'cccbb', 'cccbc', 'cccca', 'ccccb', 'ccccc']

>>> perms_rev = itertools.product(symbols[::-1], repeat=5)
>>> perms_rev = ["".join(x) for x in perms_rev]
>>> perms_rev
['ccccc', 'ccccb', 'cccca', 'cccbc', 'cccbb',
 ...,
 'aaabb', 'aaaba', 'aaaac', 'aaaab', 'aaaaa']

>>> perms_rev == perms[::-1]
True
```